# navigator.getUserMedia() doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, angular, video, twilio, getusermedia

While developing video chat with angular, I faced this issue.

```
ngOnInit() {
  navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true, video: true})
    .then(res=> console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log("err: ", err));
}
```

Console result:

> err: DomException: Could not start video source

This works well on Desktop/Chrome, but never works on Android/Chrome.
I tested it on Android Emulators such as Nox App Player and Bluestacks.

I've hosted the angular project with this command.

> ng serve --host MY_IP_ADDRESS --disable-host-check --ssl

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you test this on an Android device, are you doing so on localhost or over HTTPS? You can only use `getUserMedia` on a secure domain or localhost.

If I need to test on a device, I use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel to my localhost. You can then access the ngrok URL over HTTPS.

Another reason this might not work is that you're using the camera in another application or browser tab, and the device only allows access to the camera from one application at a time.

For the emulators, make sure you have cameras configured correctly within the emulator.

Comment: Exactly, I used ngrok to serve my localhost as https before and as I mentioned above I used ``ng serve --host MY_IP_ADDRESS --disable-host-check --ssl`` command to host my localhost as https, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is the camera in use by another application?

Comment: It isn't used by another application.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you tried turning the device off and then back on again, then trying to load the camera?

Comment: Also, can you try this test application with your device to see if it works: https://philnash.github.io/mediadevices-camera-selection/. I've used Android devices on this page successfully before, so if you can't, it might just be your device.